# Google Chrome doesn't open on click "View in Browser"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019

Using Visual Studio 2019 for ASP.Net application, when I right click and choose "**View in Browser (Chrome Browser)**" it doesn't open or no response whereas when I change and set default as internet explore "*View In Browser (Internet Explorer)*" it work fine. Anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH6JR.png)

click the drop down in the run and debug button and make sure chrome is selected, 
Hope this helped